# Why was there so little traffic to Alderaan?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

Is there any canon, or even Legends reason to explain why such an important core world like Alderaan had so little traffic to it before it was destroyed? Did the Empire broadcast out barring ships from entering?

Comment: How are you judging the amount of traffic?  Also, what constitutes "enough" traffic as opposed to "too little?"

Comment: @DavidW there was only the one fighter besides the falcon.

Comment: Are you talking about the scene where the _Falcon_ arrives in the Alderaan system and is captured?  _After_ Alderaan has been destroyed and presumably warnings have been posted?

Comment: I guess this could've been answered with a certain line from *Hitchhikers Guide to the Galaxy*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well first of all this question has a fundamental assumption; that being there was any way to even vaguely gauge the amount of space traffic around Alderaan based on what was shown in ANH, when in reality there really wasn't. It was only viewed from high orbit, and one wouldn't expect to see much of anything from that distance. Even the cities aren't clearly visible, never mind relatively tiny starships. After it was destroyed, it's a fair bet any local traffic in low orbit (including satellites and other orbital facilities) would have been caught in the blast and annihilated.

Secondly; Alderaan is not Coruscant, which does indeed have visible traffic from a significant distance, but only because of sheer volume. Alderaan is indeed a major power in galactic politics, but the planet itself is not heavily urbanised or overly industrialised, so it's not going to be a major trading or logistics hub. As with Naboo, Alderaan's wealth isn't directly from bulk material goods, or it's location in relation to major trade routes but more from it's status as a centre for science, education, arts, diplomacy, and technological artisanry. What that all means is that there's not likely to be an unusual amount visitors coming and going. Certainly nothing approaching the constant cloud of vessels that can be seen buzzing around an ecumenopolis.

Thirdly; the single TIE the Falcon ran into before being grabbed in the tractor beam  would imply that the Empire had indeed picketed the system, and likely did so as soon as the Death Star jumped in. As such, by the time the Falcon arrived it's likely that any ships far enough away to survive the blast either fled, or were intercepted. Likewise for any new arrivals, as we saw with the Falcon itself.

Comment: It's worse than that.  Even assuming 100k passenger ships and 100k cargo ships/day docking at Alderaan (enough to move >1% of the planetary population every day and also feed the entire planet), if we allow 10min for a ship to depart and jump to hyperspace or arrive and land (several times what a fast ship like the _Falcon_ required) then there are fewer than 4000 ships in flight at any one time.  Spread over 20% of the planet's land area (c.1e8 km^2) that's 1/25 000km^2 or 150km separation, counting only horizontal (not vertical) separation.  You'd be lucky to see more than 1.